# To_dict with all columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Let's say I have the following pandas dataframe:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame([{'file_name': 'my_movie.mov', 'status': 'final'}, {'file_name': 'his_movie.mov', 'status': 'source'}, {'file_name': 'her_movie.mov', 'status': 'source'}])
>>> df.groupby('status').agg({'file_name': 'first', 'status': 'size'}).rename(columns={'status': 'count'}).reset_index()
   status      file_name  count
0   final   my_movie.mov      1
1  source  his_movie.mov      2
```

How would I get that into a python `dict` with all the columns? It seems the default chops off some columns when I do it:

```
>>> df.to_dict('records')
[{'file_name': 'my_movie.mov', 'status': 'final'}, {'file_name': 'his_movie.mov', 'status': 'source'}, {'file_name': 'her_movie.mov', 'status': 'source'}]
```

Why doesn't the field `count` show in  the output?

---

Update: the solution is that I forgot to assign `df` in the second statement. Assigning that fixes it (of course).

Comment: You never assign your groupby back to `df`

Comment: @G.Anderson ha, that's right thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.groupby()` had no effect on the underlying dataframe.

Use `.to_dict()` on the expression you care about:

```
>>> import pprint
>>> 
>>> df = pd.DataFrame([{'file_name': 'my_movie.mov', 'status': 'final'}, {'file_name': 'his_movie.mov', 'status': 'source'}, {'file_name': 'her_movie.mov', 'status': 'source'}])
>>> 
>>> pprint.pprint(df.groupby('status').agg({'file_name': 'first', 'status': 'size'}).rename(columns={'status': 'count'}).reset_index()
                    .to_dict('records'))
[{'count': 1, 'file_name': 'my_movie.mov', 'status': 'final'},
 {'count': 2, 'file_name': 'his_movie.mov', 'status': 'source'}]
```

Or assign the group-by result to some dataframe variable such as `g`,
and then `g.to_dict(...)` will give you what you want.

Comment: ok, so it's in adding the `.reset_index` that fixes it.

Comment: @samuelbrody1249 no -- it's operating on/assigning/printing the result of the operation instead of the original dataframe, like you did.

Comment: @PaulH oh, I see, in the second line I just forgot to assign it. Thanks.